# bootstrap select js add 'open' not working

Tags: javascript, html

[image]
i need classadd open. but does not allow.

onchange="tabenter()";

```
function tabenter()

{
    var element = document.querySelector('.tt');
    element.classList.add("open");
   // or
$(".tt").addClass('openn');

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not allow"? Do you get any error?

Comment: where are you calling the onchange event?

Comment: not error, just do not add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery to bind event handelers instead of inline event handler,
here is an example:

```js
$('#selectBox').on('change', function() {
  $('.tt').addClass('open');
})
```

```css
.open{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectBox">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<p class ="tt">
I will change my class
</p>
```

Comment: It works when added to the console. but add js not working

Comment: try ctrl+ f5 on your browser.

Comment: I've edited the question with sample code, try this.